# Condition `Failed` attempting to approve CSRs with `certificates.k8s.io/v1`

Tags: kubernetes

I've a working ValidatingWebhookConfiguration and have been creating|approving CSRs with `certificates.k8s.io/v1beta`.

I upgraded (MicroK8s) from 1.18 to 1.20 and received a warning that `certificates.k8s.io/v1beta` is deprecated 1.19+ and thought I'd try (without success) upgrading to `certificates.k8s.io/v1`.

Existing (working) CSR:

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat ${FILENAME}.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
```

Upgrading the API generated an error:

```
missing required field "signerName" in io.k8s.api.certificates.v1.CertificateSigningRequestSpec;
```

I read the CSR doc specifically the part about [Kubernetes signers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#kubernetes-signers) and, because my existing spec uses `server auth`, assumed I could use `kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving` since this is the only one that permits `server auth`.

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1                      <<--- UPGRADED
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat ${FILENAME}.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving              <<--- ADDED
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
```

However, I get errors trying to approve the CSR (as a cluster admin):

```
kubectl certificate approve ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}
certificatesigningrequest.certificates.k8s.io/${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE} approved

kubectl get csr ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}
NAME                      SIGNERNAME                      REQUESTOR   CONDITION
${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}   kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving   admin       Approved,Failed
```

> **NOTE** `Approved` but `Failed`

And I'm unable to get the certificate (presumably because it `Failed`):

```
kubectl get csr ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE} \
--output=jsonpath='{.status.certificate}'
```

How should I use the `certificates.k8s.io/v1` API?

#### Update: 2021-01-06

OK, so I realized I have more information on the "Failed" and this gives me something to investigate...

```sh
kubectl get csr/${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE} \
--output=jsonpath="{.status}" \
| jq .
```

Yields:

```
{
  "conditions": [
    {
      "lastTransitionTime": "2021-01-06T18:52:15Z",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2021-01-06T18:52:15Z",
      "message": "This CSR was approved by kubectl certificate approve.",
      "reason": "KubectlApprove",
      "status": "True",
      "type": "Approved"
    },
    {
      "lastTransitionTime": "2021-01-06T18:52:15Z",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2021-01-06T18:52:15Z",
      "message": "subject organization is not system:nodes",
      "reason": "SignerValidationFailure",
      "status": "True",
      "type": "Failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Update: 2021-01-07

Thanks @PjoterS

```sh
ubectl describe csr/${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}
Name:         eldlund.utopial
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"certificates.k8s.io/v1","kind":"CertificateSigningRequest","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"eldlund.utopial"},"spec":{"groups":["system:authenticated"],"request":"LS0tLS1C...LS0tLS0K","signerName":"kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving","usages":["digital signature","key encipherment","server auth"]}}

CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 07 Jan 2021 17:03:23 +0000
Requesting User:    admin
Signer:             kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving
Status:             Pending
Subject:
  Common Name:    eldlund.utopial.svc
  Serial Number:  
Subject Alternative Names:
         DNS Names:  eldlund.utopial.svc
                     eldlund.utopial.svc.cluster.local
Events:  <none>
```

#### Signing w/ OpenSSL (rather than Kubernetes)

I tried creating CA crt|key and then a service key|CSR and signing the service CSR with the CA but Kubernetes complains:

```
x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match ainsley.utopial.svc
```

Yet the certificate appears to contain both CN and SAN entries:

**DOESN'T WORK**

```sh
openssl x509 -in ${FILENAME}.crt --noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            6f:14:25:8c:...
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = Validating Webhook CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  7 18:10:50 2021 GMT
            Not After : Feb  6 18:10:50 2021 GMT
        Subject: CN = ainsley.utopial.svc
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ca:56:15:...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:ainsley.utopial.svc, DNS:ainsley.utopial.svc.cluster.local
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         b2:ec:22:b6:...
```

> **NOTE** `CN` is a DNS name above but an IP below ???

Reverting to my working solution with `v1beta1` and changing the service name for completeness (`loi`), the Webhook succeeds and the certificate appears to be no different from the one shown above (except the different service name):

**WORKS**

```sh
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            ff:b3:cb:11:...
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = 10.152.183.1
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  7 18:18:45 2021 GMT
            Not After : Jan  7 18:18:45 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN = loi.utopial.svc
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d2:cc:c2:...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:E7:AE:3A:25:95:D2:F7:5B:C6:EA:50:56:07:E8:25:83:60:88:68:7A

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:loi.utopial.svc, DNS:loi.utopial.svc.cluster.local
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         48:a1:b2:e2:...
```

Comment: Could you provide describe output of your CSR `kubectl describe csr <csrName>`? When you are [downloading your CSR](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#download-the-certificate-and-use-it) are you getting output or its empty?

Comment: Thanks for replying, @pjoters. I've updated my question with the describe results.

Comment: I discovered [this](https://github.com/stackrox/admission-controller-webhook-demo/tree/master) link last night and it may hold my solution. It doesn't use Kubernetes for CSR. Checking whether it works now

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Switched to [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io) and everything working [well](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/210108/)

I got it working but I'm unsure why what I'm now doing is correct.

And the `openssl` feels unwieldy (advice appreciated).

#### Environment

```sh
DIR=${PWD}/secrets
SERVICE="..."
NAMESPACE="..."

FILENAME="${DIR}/${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}"
```

#### CA

```sh
openssl req \
-nodes \
-new \
-x509 \
-keyout ${FILENAME}.ca.key \
-out ${FILENAME}.ca.crt \
-subj "/CN=Validating Webhook CA"
```

#### Create (Webhook) Service

Necessary to set the service certificate's CN to the IP

```sh
cat ./kubernetes/service.yaml \
| sed "s|SERVICE|${SERVICE}|g" \
| sed "s|NAMESPACE|${NAMESPACE}|g" \
| kubectl apply --filename=- --namespace=${NAMESPACE}

ENDPOINT=$(\
  kubectl get service/${SERVICE} \
  --namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
  --output=jsonpath="{.spec.clusterIP}") && echo ${ENDPOINT}
```

#### Create CSR

Even though I include the CN and `alt_names` here, I must duplicate the SAN stuff (next step)

```sh
echo "[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn
req_extensions = req_ext

[ dn ]
commonName = ${ENDPOINT}

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc
DNS.2 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local
" > ${FILENAME}.cfg

openssl req \
-nodes \
-new \
-sha256 \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-keyout ${FILENAME}.key \
-out ${FILENAME}.csr \
-config ${FILENAME}.cfg
```

#### Create CSR extension

Unsure why I must duplicate (or separate) this content. If I omit this from the `openssl x509 -extfile`, the certificate contains no SAN extension.

```sh
printf "subjectAltName=DNS:${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc,DNS:${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local" > ${FILENAME}.ext
```

#### Create service certificate

How can I use a single CSR for everything rather than CSR+EXT?

```sh
openssl x509 \
-req \
-in ${FILENAME}.csr \
-extfile ${FILENAME}.ext \
-CA ${FILENAME}.ca.crt \
-CAkey ${FILENAME}.ca.key \
-CAcreateserial \
-out ${FILENAME}.crt
```

#### Create (Webhook) Deployment

The underlying implementation of the webhook needs the service's crt|key

```sh
kubectl create secret tls ${SERVICE} \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
--cert=${FILENAME}.crt \
--key=${FILENAME}.key

cat ./kubernetes/deployment.yaml \
| sed "s|SERVICE|${SERVICE}|g" \
| sed "s|NAMESPACE|${NAMESPACE}|g" \
| kubectl apply --filename=- --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

#### Create Webhook

Grab the CA certificate

```sh
CABUNDLE=$(openssl base64 -A <"${FILENAME}.ca.crt")

cat ./kubernetes/webhook.yaml \
| sed "s|SERVICE|${SERVICE}|g" \
| sed "s|NAMESPACE|${NAMESPACE}|g" \
| sed "s|CABUNDLE|${CABUNDLE}|g" \
| kubectl apply --filename=- --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, by mocking your apps CSR's with kubelet-like requests, you can continue to have the k8s certificates created.  I have the details in this issue, https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/26111, trying to get the k8s docs to be more useful on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the ping. The documentation isn't sufficiently generalized in this regard. I'd assumed that this process (i.e. for non-core resources) had become discouraged. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While generating .csr from OpenSSL you can add "system:node" and "O=system:nodes" in CN(i.e. common name) as below and then use your upgraded certificates.k8s.io/v1.

*Before change OpenSSL command*
openssl req -new -key ${tmpdir}/server-key.pem -subj "/CN=${title}.${namespace}.svc" -out ${tmpdir}/server.csr -config ${tmpdir}/csr.conf

*After change OpenSSL command*
openssl req -new -key ${tmpdir}/server-key.pem -subj "/CN=**system:node:**${title}.${namespace}.svc;**/O=system:nodes**" -out ${tmpdir}/server.csr -config ${tmpdir}/csr.conf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).